# How to set seed value and incremental value for identity column in Azure Synapse?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

I have a table with DDL as below in the Azure Synapse Data Warehouse:

```
CREATE TABLE [test].[test_history]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [test1] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [test2] [varchar](100) NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( [test1] ),
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
GO
```

I tried to append values into this table 3 times with the sql below, the id column has a seed value of 45 and incremental value of 60 inspite of the IDENTITY(1,1).

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME2 = GETDATE()

INSERT INTO test.test_history
(test1, test2)
VALUES ('test', '2022-02-18-03')

SELECT * FROM test.test_history
```

Also, I check the seed value as 1 and incremental value as 1 with the SQL below. However, the table does not provide the id value as expected

How can I fix this issue ?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IDENTITY` columns in Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated SQL pools do guarantee unique values but [do not guarantee sequential values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-identity?#allocation-of-values). The reason is because data is split across 60 distributions; each distribution has a unique set of identity values.

If it's important for you to have a sequential column then recreate the table without the `IDENTITY` property and change your `INSERT` statement to the following code which will produce a sequential ID:

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME2 = GETDATE()

INSERT INTO trans_customer_cdm_ejkb.cdm_file_process_history
(id, layer, ingest_partition, [status], last_update_time, pipeline_run_id)
SELECT
(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id),0) FROM trans_customer_cdm_ejkb.cdm_file_process_history) +1 as id, 
 'src2stg', '2022-02-18-03', 'success', @now, 'Test'

SELECT * FROM trans_customer_cdm_ejkb.cdm_file_process_history
```

Since your code was just inserting a single row I did `+1` but normally you would do  `+ ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [SomeColumn])`.